# A little php help with this string formatting

Tags: php

I have a string in this format:

```
    /SV/temp_images/766321929_2.jpg
```

Is there any small piece of code to get the numbers BEFORE the underscore, BUT AFTER temp_images/? In this case I want to get **766321929** only... ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
$str = '/SV/temp_images/766321929_2.jpg';
$m = array();
if (preg_match('#temp_images/(\d+)_#', $str, $m)) {
    echo $m[1];
}
```

The idea :

- Use [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/preg_match) with a regular expression

  - that works with anything that begins with '`temp_images/`'
  - and ends with '`_`'
  - but only returns the numbers (symbolized by `\d`) found between those
- And the third parameter, `$m`, will contain what was matched :

  - `$m[0]` will be everything that was matched
  - `$m[1]` will be the first captured *(between `()`)* part -- i.e. what you are looking for, here

And the output :

```
766321929
```

And if you're curious and what to know more about regex, don't hesitate to take a look at [Regular Expressions (Perl-Compatible)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) -- there is a lot of interesting stuff to read, there ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '/SV/temp_images/766321929_2.jpg';
list($numbers) = explode('_', basename($str));
echo $numbers;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dirty way:

```
$contents = ' /SV/temp_images/766321929_2.jpg';
$contents = substr($contents, strpos($contents, 'temp_images/'));
$contents = substr($contents, strpos($contents, '/'));
$contents = substr($contents, 1);
$contents = substr($contents, 0, strpos($contents, '_'));
print $contents;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [basename](http://www.php.net/basename) and then [explode](http://www.php.net/explode) the resultant filename as such...

```
$fileComponents = explode('_', basename($filePathString));
$requiredComponent = $fileComponents[0];
```

That said, you'd need to add sanity checking, etc. as required.

Answer (score 0):

Generic solution not tied to a specific directory:

```
$name = preg_replace('/_.*/', '', basename($string));
```